# Differences between mini USB and micro USB in circuit design?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, usb

Hopefully a quick and silly question -

I am looking to modify a reference design such as this one:

http://www.microbuilder.eu/Files/Projects/LPC1343RefDesign/LPC1343_Schematic_v1.6.pdf

And was wondering if I could replace the Mini USB with a Micro USB without much hastle. What signals / connections would have to change?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mini-USB and micro-USB have the same functionality, number of pins (5), and pin order.  The only thing that would need to be changed is the part number/symbol on the schematic, and the footprint on the PCB (since the pins are in the same order, there should be little change in the layout other than accompanying the different footprint).

Comment: There could be an issue if going from a mini in a normal right angle orientation to a micro with an inverted orientation. In such case the order of the pins on the PCB would flip over.

Comment: @MichaelKaras This is possible, but usually USB connectors (both mini and micro) are oriented the same way so the USB logo on the cable is visible from the top.  Even if the connector is mounted on the bottom of the board, there are special connectors for that to keep the pin orientation the same (the pins come out the the "top" rather than the bottom) -- it's not simple flipped over.